# draw smooth line between html elements using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, javascript, jquery-layout

I wants to draw smooth line between html element using jquery. 
Does Jquery has any plugins to draw smooth line using Jquery ?
I have used SVG plugin but it is not supported in IE7,IE8.
I have also used div to draw line but it has many jaggies.

Any idea is gratly appriciated. Plugin should support atleast IE7 and greter version, Mozila and crome.
Thanks.

http://servut.us/akx/stackoverflow/jquery-canvas-lines.html
i wants to made like the above link. But the problem with above link is that it is not working in IE 7,8.

Answer (score 1):

There are some [complicated ways](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/javascriptlinedrawing.aspx) you could achieve this, but most likely you will want to use an HTML5 [canvas](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html) and its methods `moveTo` and `lineTo`. If you need to support older browsers without canvas support (like IE7, and IE8), then you can use a canvas [polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) to help you achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Until HTML 5 becomes widespread, your best bet for dynamic graphics is probably rendering the image on the server, and referencing it with an  HTML tag over on the client.

Both GD (if you're using PHP) and System.Drawing (if you're using .Net) make this relatively easy.

Comment: i am using JAVA. and i would like to draw line using Jquery or css.

Answer (score -1):

Use css borders , it should have all kind of nice border

sample

```
border-top-style:dotted;
border-right-style:solid;
border-bottom-style:dotted;
border-left-style:solid;
```

Comment: Thanx, But This can only possible in top right bottom and left lines. What about diagonal lines. i want so many lines between html element.it may be horizontal vertical,or in any order.